# Main character with indestructible armor who fights dragons, and later learns he is one

Tags: story-identification

The main character gets some armor, which makes him basically invincible, for the purpose of killing dragons.  Later on the he learns that he is actually a dragon with a powerful spell cast on him to keep him in a humanoid (elf I think) form.  He breaks the spell and becomes a dragon, then gets some kind of dragon armor that makes him more powerful, to fight evil dragons. It may have been a trilogy, or even six books.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *Mystara: The Dragonlord Chronicles Book Series* by Thorarinn Gunnarsson.  This sounds like the plot of the first book in the series:  *[Dragonlord of Mystara](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/612826.Dragonlord_of_Mystara)*.

[image: Book cover]

The main character is an orphan who gains the armor of the DragonLord.  Due to their fear of a prophecy and the powers of the Dragonlord, dragons try to find and kill the main character.  Eventually, we learn that he is actually a dragon himself and destined to be the dragonking.